# Sending and receiving a list via bluetooth

Tags: android, list, bluetooth

One of the features my app must have is to compare a list that it has created with a list of the same format that another phone has created. In order to do this I need to implement bluetooth file transfer, but I don't know anything about it yet. Can someone please give me a head start?

Comment: Have you went through the [Android Bluetooth Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) yet? Understanding how to handle bluetooth connections can be a little tricky at first so I think you need a good handle on that before actually trying to transfer data. Good Luck

Comment: I did read something about it, but I am working on something for school that is due soon, so I was rather looking for an example that I could implement, since I only need very simple functionality and not something complex, like a bluetooth game for example, and I don't have time to work on that part for long. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same question, I just used the Bluetooth Chat sample, and for the simple thing I needed it worked like a charm! Should have done it before asking, sorry about that.